# Place text between top and center of the screen

Tags: ios, view, swiftui

Is there a simple way to place text relatively between the top and center of the screen? With 'simple' I mean preferably without `GeometryReader` and overt calculations.

I've tried various combinations of `VStack`, `Zstack` and `Spacer()` but to no avail.

Code and screenshot as illustration:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Between top and center")
            .offset(y: -150)
        Text("Center")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create two views on each side of the centred text (one hidden):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Between top and center")
            Spacer()
            Text("Center")
            Spacer()
            Text("")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, to be fool-proof (in case they change the behaviour of `Text("")` in the future release):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Between top and center")
            Spacer()
            Text("Center")
            Spacer()
            Text("Between top and center")
                .opacity(0)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

(If needed, `Text("Between top and center")` can be extracted as a subview to avoid code duplication.)

---

As you said:

> `Spacer()` [...] ensure[s] that the empty spaces between the views are equal in size

That's exactly the reason why I recommended to extract `Text("Between top and center")` as a subview. Then, you can change the font, size etc. of the view in one place only.

The adapted solution is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                subview
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                subview
                    .opacity(0)
                Spacer()
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Center")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

    var subview: some View {
        Text("Between top and center")
            .font(.caption)
            // apply all other modifiers if you want
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad - this doesn't work. I already tried something like this before. The problem is that what `Spacer()` does very much depends on the size of the views (fonts). All it does is ensure that the empty spaces between the views are equal in size. It doesn't actually ensure that the center text remains in the center.

Comment: @Daan It does work if you make both views the same font (including the hidden one).

Comment: That’s the problem: I use different font sizes for the center and between-top-and-center text, and the sizes also change dynamically. So the relative placement shouldn’t depend on font size.

Comment: @Daan I see - please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't quite work, but you can fix it by replacing the second `subview` in the first `VStack` by a `Spacer()`.

Comment: @Daan Actually I just missed a `Spacer`, apologies for not testing it. I added a missing `Spacer`. The idea is that the first part (1st spacer, subview, 2nd spacer) fills the top half of the screen and the second part (3rd spacer, hidden subview, 4th spacer) fills the bottom one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
          Color.clear.overlay(
             Text("Between top and center") // << here !!
          )
//        Text("Between top and center")
//          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)  // alternate !!
          Text("Center")
          Color.clear
       }
    }
}
```

**Update:** added alternate with `.frame` but it is valid only if there should be the only one Text, whereas in `.overlay` it is possible to put anything.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Not to be too nit-picky but is a similarly simple way to achieve this without using color elements? Perhaps with `frame`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using the method of VStack Spacers, I also used a little padding to get you closer to the center.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Top").bold()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Spacer()
            Text("Your desired area")
            Spacer()
            Text("Middle Text").bold()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .padding(.bottom, 200)
            Spacer()
                
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't hardcode any padding. It needs to be relative center and relative between top and center.